# Menu in header reloads everytime a user clicks on the links. How to change the color of the current link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, hyperlink

I have a header.jsp which is included in all pages of my application. The header also contains the navigation menu with 4 page links. When a user will click one of these links to go to the respective page, the whole page reloads. How can i change the color of the link for the current page in the header. below is the header.

```
<td class="navBtn"  onClick="className='navBtnSel';"><a href="ReportingTemplate.jsp"     class="bannerHeader" title="Reporting Search"  target="_parent">Customer</a></td>
                <td class="navBtn"  onClick="className='navBtnSel';"><a href="BraTemplate.jsp" class="bannerHeader" title="Reporting Search"  target="_parent">Branch</a></td>
                <td class="navBtn"  onClick="className='navBtnSel';"><a href="DDReportTemplate.jsp" class="bannerHeader" title="Reports"  target="_parent">Reports</a></td>
                <td class="navBtn"  onClick="className='navBtnSel';"><a href="CreateUserprf.do" class="bannerHeader" title="Create User"  target="_parent">Create User</a></td>
                <td class="navBtn"  onClick="className='navBtnSel';"><div style="padding-right: 14px;"><a href="LogOutAction.do" class="bannerHeader" title="Log Out"  target="_parent">Log Out</a></div></td>
```

and this header is included in other pages as below..

```
 <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left"><iframe src ="Header.jsp?stflg=C" name="head" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" id="head" style="height: 150px; width: 100%;"></iframe></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="searchCell" width="21%" align="left"><iframe style="height: 590px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 0px; width: 250px;" frameborder="0" id="search" name="search" src ="SearchFill.do" scrolling="no"></iframe></td>
      <td id="bodyCell"width="79%"><iframe style="height: 590px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" frameborder="0" id="body" name="body" scrolling="auto" src="body.jsp"></iframe></td>
  </tr>
```

I am a beginner in front end. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like menu_id into each menu-link. Example:

```
<a href="BranchTemplate.jsp?menu_id=2" ... </a>
```

The menu_id variable will serve to identify active menu.

Comment: Here is an example how to check variable from link:

`<%
 String id = request.getParameter( 'menu_id' );
 if( null != id && !id.equals( "" ) )
 {
   // apply some css style for specific menu (based on menu_id) to mark menu as Active
 }
 %>`

Answer (score 0):

You first need a method of reliably identifying the current page.  I've found it effective to add a unique ID to each body tag, and an ID to each link, resulting in something like this:

```
<body id="about">
  ....
  <nav>
    <a class="n-main" href="main.html">
    <a class="n-about" href="about.html">
  </nav>
```

Then you can re-style current links with a specification like this:

```
body#main a.n-main, body#about a.n-about { color: red; }
```

Only the link which is inside the `body#about` will turn red.

Using backend code, you could also add a `.current` class to the appropriate link, and then just write a style specification for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to investigate some server-side technologies to handle the 'include' you are trying to do with the `iframe`. (Like PHP, ASP.NET, etc.)

With your `iframe` approach, you are going to make navigating between pages far more complicated than it needs to be.